# Dynamic filter in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in excel 2016 worksheet in which there is one numeric column. I have added hyperlinks on these column values.
If we click on any number, Filter gets applied/updated on data present in other sheet.

To achieve this, Is it requires macro or we can achieve this Excel functionality only

Thanks in advance.
~Aj

Comment: Easy to do with VBA macros, especially if the hyperlinks are **Inserted** rather than `=HYPERLINK()` function calls.

Comment: Not clear what you mean with 'filter applied on data present in other sheet'. Clicking on a link should do what exactly? Try to provide an example, it will make it easier to solve the question.